# How do I link two HTML pages in a web application?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've got two HTML pages, with one being an opening page for an application and the second being a login page. I have a button on the opening page and I want to be able to click on it and have it take me to the login page. How do I do this?

Comment: <a href="page2"><button>Take me to second page</button></a> - are you asking for a simple link?

Comment: You should NOT use <button> for links, use <a> for them.

Comment: Don't use a button as browsers might treat them differently. If you must, style a `<a>` tag to make it look like a button

Answer (score 3):

```
 <a href="secondpage.html"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="login.html">Login</a>`

When users click on the link above, it will take them to the login page.